# Why my logo is not appearing on the Homepage?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hello I would like to know why my logo is not appearing on the Homepage but on all the other pages it is?

website: http://www.abraham-accountants.co.uk/

Comment: Hi there. Questions that mostly or entirely rely on external links are not a good fit here, since they are not of any value if the material at the external link is fixed. For your next question, please add everything required in the post itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which logo you are referring to but I see it just fine on your home page. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Could you let me know if there are other logos you seem to be missing??
Any additional information would help.
Thanks.

Comment: I just realized it just got updated

Comment: Hello I do make Chartered Certified Accounts writing a bit smaller but stay in the same postion

Comment: In your style.css file, try lowering the font size in the selector `#logo .site-description`. I got it down to about 2.2em from 2.5em before the positioning caused it to go out of bound. If you need it to go smaller than 2.2em, you would probably need to re work the CSS positioning of the header logo.

Comment: I am using firebug tool and when i move the logo a bit up I when i am lowering size it still don't same in the same position.

Comment: #logo .site-description {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #004488;
  font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, Arial, Tahoma;
}

Comment: This code I testing in firebug how do i make position under Abraham & Co heading

Comment: Well firebug tool only lets you edit the code on your browser. The "actual" or "source" code is stored on the server hosting your wordpress site. You need to make the change there for it to be permanent. Otherwise every time you hit refresh, your browser is going to pull the same old source code from the server.

Comment: Yes I know that but I am not getting the outcome I want

Comment: Ah I see, anything pass 2.2em is causing the header to go out of positioning. Let me look into it a bit more on how it's being positioned.

Comment: Try changing the position to fixed and manually positioning it. Add the following towards the end after changing it to `1.1em`
 `position: fixed;
  top: 135px;
  left: 590px;`

Comment: Actually just realized fixed positioning would not work since a lot of the other elements are positioned relatively. If you start scrolling down, you will noticed that the header is fixed and scrolls down with it. I would look into alternatives to position that header.

Comment: Thank You I have put back to normal because i'm on way to home if you do find the solution i will have look as soon I am home and have a try. Thank you for helping :).

Comment: No problem. I work mostly on the back-end of web development so it'll probably take me a while to figure out the CSS styling to properly scale down the logo text. I would recommend you post this question with just HTML/CSS in the tags to get some input from front-end developers as they would be able to come up with a much faster solution that I would. As always please try to supply them with as much detail as possible, perhaps the screenshot I used in my response?

Comment: I fixed it I had to remove float: left; on #logo .site-title and #logo .site-description.